# jQuery add id via attr not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a to do list, and adding a remove and completed functionality to the list. However, **once the remove/completed button is pressed, it is applied to the all the *li* elements**. Furthermore, if one adds more items to the list, the **buttons lose their functionality**.

I've checked the JS Console, and there are no errors. I've built a snippet to recreate the bug:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var removeImg = '<img src= "https://www.icon2s.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ios7-trash-icon.png" width = "22px" class = "removeicon">';
    var completeImg = '<img src = "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/11/28/857777_circle_512x512.png" class = "completeicon" width = "22px">';
    document.getElementById("add").addEventListener('click', function(){
        var value = document.getElementById("addtask_TD").value;
        var lookat = document.getElementById("addtask_TD");
        if (value) {
            addItemTodo(value);
            lookat.focus();
            lookat.select();
        }

    });
    function addItemTodo(text){
        var list = document.getElementById('todo');

        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.innerText = text;
        
        var buttons = document.createElement('div');
        buttons.classList.add('buttons');
        
        var remove = document.createElement('button');
        remove.classList.add('remove');
        remove.classList.add('btn');
//  $(".remove").attr("id","delete");
        remove.innerHTML = removeImg;
        
        var complete = document.createElement('button');
        complete.classList.add('complete');
        complete.classList.add('btn');
// $(".complete").attr("id","done");
        complete.innerHTML = completeImg;
        buttons.appendChild(remove);
        buttons.appendChild(complete);
        item.appendChild(buttons);
        list.appendChild(item);
 document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
            $(item).fadeOut(1000);
 });
        document.getElementsByClassName("complete")[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
            $(".completeicon").attr("src", "https://png.icons8.com/cotton/50/000000/checkmark.png");
        });
    }
});
```

```css
header{
 width:100% !important;
 height: 80px !important;
 position:fixed !important;
 top:0 !important;
 
 left:0 !important;
 z-index:5 !important;
 background: #25b99a !important;
 box-shadow:0px 2px 4px rgba(44,62,80,0.15) !important;
 padding:15px;
}

#addtask_TD {
 width:100% !important;
 height:50px !important;
 float:left !important;
 border-radius: 5px !important;
 border: 0px;
 box-shadow:none !important;
 outline:none;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:400px;
 text-indent:16px;
 border-top-right-radius:25px !important;
 border-top-left-radius:5px !important;
 border-bottom-right-radius:25px !important;
 border-bottom-left-radius:5px !important;
 text-indent:10px !important;

 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0,0.22) !important; 
}

header input:: -webkit-input-placeholder{
 color:rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}

header input:: -moz-input-placeholder{
 color:rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}
header input:: -o-input-placeholder{
 color:rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}
header input:: -ms-input-placeholder{
 color:rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}
header button {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 position:absolute;
 top: 15px;
 right:15px;
 z-index:2;
 border-radius:25px;
 background:8px;
 box-shadow:none;
 outline: none; 
 background-color:white;
 border:none;
  -o-appearance:none !important;
 -ms-appearance:none !important;
 -moz-appearance:none !important;
 -webkit-appearance:none !important;
 appearance:none !important;
 
}

header button svg{
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
}

header button svg .fill{
 fill: #25b99a;
}

ul.todo{
 width:100%;
 float:left;
  
}
.st0{fill:none;}
.st1{fill:#C0CECB;}
ul.todo li {
 width:108%;
 float:left;
 height:50px;
 position:relative;
 background:darkblue;
 border-radius:5px;
 box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(44,62,80,0.10);
 bottom: -16px;
 padding: 0 100px 0 0;
 /**margin: -20px;**/
 margin: 0 0 15px -20px;
}

.containtodolist{
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 padding: 15px;
}

ul#todo li:last-of-type{
/** margin:0;**/
}

ul#todo li .buttons {
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
}

ul#todo li .buttons button{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 float:left;
 background:none;
 border:0px;
 box-shadow:none;
 outline:none;
 position:relative;
 
 -o-appearance:none !important;
 -ms-appearance:none !important;
 -moz-appearance:none !important;
 -webkit-appearance:none !important;
 appearance:none !important;
 
}

ul#todo li .buttons button:last-of-type:before{
 content:'';
 width:1px;
 height:30px;
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left: 0;
 background:#edf0f1;
 
}

.buttons{
 display:block;
}

.noFill{
 fill:none;
}

ul#todo li .buttons button svg{
 width:22px;
 height:22px;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin: -11px 0 0 -11px;
}

li{
 background-color:lightblue;
 margin: 65px 0 -70px 0;
 padding-top:7px;
 padding-bottom:24px;
 padding-left:50px;
 
 border-top: 6px solid #79afaf;
  right: 40px;
}

.remove,.complete{
 margin: 10px;

}

.remove,.complete{
  padding-top: 6px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class = "containtodolist">
    <header>
        <input id = "addtask_TD" type = "text" placeholder = "Add task">
        <button id = "add"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 16;" xml:space="preserve"><g><path class="fill" d="M16,8c0,0.5-0.5,1-1,1H9v6c0,0.5-0.5,1-1,1s-1-0.5-1-1V9H1C0.5,9,0,8.5,0,8s0.5-1,1-1h6V1c0-0.5,0.5-1,1-1s1,0.5,1,1v6h6C15.5,7,16,7.5,16,8z"/></g></svg></button>
    </header> 
    <div class = "container_TD" id = "todo">
<!-- <ul class = "todo" id = "completed">
            <li> WHouha 
                    <div class = "buttons">
                            <button class = "remove"> <img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/delete.png" width = "22px"></button>
                            <button class = "complete"><img src = "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/11/28/857777_circle_512x512.png" width = "22px"> </button>
                    </div>
            </li>
    </ul>-->
    </div>  
    <ul class = "todo" id = "completed"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You only add the event listener to `[0]`, so just the first button of each type.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and plain JS like this? If you're using jQuery, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements for how to bind events one time for all the dynamic elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jquery, you should use jquery to select elements and to apply click events, dont mix in vanilla js's `getElementsByClassName` and `addEventListener`. It will make your code harder to read and maintain in the future.

Issue 1:

> once the remove/completed button is pressed, it is applied to the all
>   the li elements

this is because when you do

```
      $(".completeicon").attr("src", "https://png.icons8.com/cotton/50/000000/checkmark.png")
```

That is the jquery equivalent of selecting all elements of the class `.completeicon`, so clicking one triggers all of them. That's why everything completes.

Everything removing happens for a different reason:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
      $(item).fadeOut(1000);
    });
```

Whenever you add a todo, you only ever assign the remove event to the first remove button in the first todo (because it is `document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0]`). But, each time you call `addEventListener`, `item` represents the latest item added to the list. So clicking the first remove, will successively remove itself and each other item on the list.

This also explains issue 2:

> Furthermore, if one adds more items to the list, the buttons lose
>   their functionality.

That is because again, you are only ever applying the events to the first item on the list (the `[0]`<sup>th</sup> item).

To solve it, instead of using `document.getElementsByClassName` to select the DOM elements apply events to, you can just apply events directly to the variables of your various DOM elements, which is handy and IMHO easier to read:

Just before this:

```
 buttons.appendChild(remove);
 buttons.appendChild(complete);
 item.appendChild(buttons);

 list.appendChild(item);
```

You can do

```
$(remove).click(function(){
    $(item).fadeOut(1000);
});

$(complete).click(function(){
    $(this).find('.completeicon').attr('src',"https://png.icons8.com/cotton/50/000000/checkmark.png")
});
```

Which just targets the latest `remove` button and `complete` button that is about to be added. Then just remove the `addEventListener` code completely.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I understand now, and it executes perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

simply replace

```
document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    $(item).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

with

```
remove.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $(item).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

you don't need to query the dom, just append the handler to your `remove` variable.

**EDIT**

OOPS, I had forgotten about the *completion* part

replace

```
document.getElementsByClassName("complete")[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    $(".completeicon").attr("src", "https://png.icons8.com/cotton/50/000000/checkmark.png");
});
```

with

```
complete.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $(this).children('.completeicon').attr('src', "https://png.icons8.com/cotton/50/000000/checkmark.png")
});
```

too

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var removeImg = '<img src= "https://www.icon2s.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ios7-trash-icon.png" width = "22px" class = "removeicon">';
 var completeImg = '<img src = "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/11/28/857777_circle_512x512.png" class = "completeicon" width = "22px">';
 document.getElementById("add").addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  var value = document.getElementById("addtask_TD").value;
  var lookat = document.getElementById("addtask_TD");
  if(value) {
   addItemTodo(value);
   lookat.focus();
   lookat.select();
  }
  
 });
 
 function addItemTodo(text){
  var list = document.getElementById('todo');
  
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  item.innerText = text;
  
  var buttons = document.createElement('div');
  buttons.classList.add('buttons');
  
  var remove = document.createElement('button');
  remove.classList.add('remove');
  remove.classList.add('btn');
//  $(".remove").attr("id","delete");
  remove.innerHTML = removeImg;
  
  var complete = document.createElement('button');
  complete.classList.add('complete');
  complete.classList.add('btn');
 // $(".complete").attr("id","done");

  complete.innerHTML = completeImg;
  
  buttons.appendChild(remove);
  buttons.appendChild(complete);
  item.appendChild(buttons);
  
  list.appendChild(item);
 
 
remove.addEventListener('click', function(){
 $(item).fadeOut(1000);
 });

complete.addEventListener('click', function(){
 $(this).children('.completeicon').attr('src', "https://png.icons8.com/cotton/50/000000/checkmark.png")

});
 
 }
});
```

```css
header{
 width:100% !important;
 height: 80px !important;
 position:fixed !important;
 top:0 !important;
 
 left:0 !important;
 z-index:5 !important;
 background: #25b99a !important;
 box-shadow:0px 2px 4px rgba(44,62,80,0.15) !important;
 padding:15px;
}

#addtask_TD {
 width:100% !important;
 height:50px !important;
 float:left !important;
 border-radius: 5px !important;
 border: 0px;
 box-shadow:none !important;
 outline:none;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:400px;
 text-indent:16px;
 border-top-right-radius:25px !important;
 border-top-left-radius:5px !important;
 border-bottom-right-radius:25px !important;
 border-bottom-left-radius:5px !important;
 text-indent:10px !important;

 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0,0.22) !important; 
}

header input:: -webkit-input-placeholder{
 color:rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}

header input:: -moz-input-placeholder{
 color:rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}
header input:: -o-input-placeholder{
 color:rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}
header input:: -ms-input-placeholder{
 color:rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}
header button {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 position:absolute;
 top: 15px;
 right:15px;
 z-index:2;
 border-radius:25px;
 background:8px;
 box-shadow:none;
 outline: none; 
 background-color:white;
 border:none;
  -o-appearance:none !important;
 -ms-appearance:none !important;
 -moz-appearance:none !important;
 -webkit-appearance:none !important;
 appearance:none !important;
 
}

header button svg{
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
}

header button svg .fill{
 fill: #25b99a;
}

ul.todo{
 width:100%;
 float:left;
  
}
.st0{fill:none;}
.st1{fill:#C0CECB;}
ul.todo li {
 width:108%;
 float:left;
 height:50px;
 position:relative;
 background:darkblue;
 border-radius:5px;
 box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(44,62,80,0.10);
 bottom: -16px;
 padding: 0 100px 0 0;
 /**margin: -20px;**/
 margin: 0 0 15px -20px;
}

.containtodolist{
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 padding: 15px;
}

ul#todo li:last-of-type{
/** margin:0;**/
}

ul#todo li .buttons {
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
}

ul#todo li .buttons button{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 float:left;
 background:none;
 border:0px;
 box-shadow:none;
 outline:none;
 position:relative;
 
 -o-appearance:none !important;
 -ms-appearance:none !important;
 -moz-appearance:none !important;
 -webkit-appearance:none !important;
 appearance:none !important;
 
}

ul#todo li .buttons button:last-of-type:before{
 content:'';
 width:1px;
 height:30px;
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left: 0;
 background:#edf0f1;
 
}

.buttons{
 display:block;
}

.noFill{
 fill:none;
}

ul#todo li .buttons button svg{
 width:22px;
 height:22px;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin: -11px 0 0 -11px;
}

li{
 background-color:lightblue;
 margin: 65px 0 -70px 0;
 padding-top:7px;
 padding-bottom:24px;
 padding-left:50px;
 
 border-top: 6px solid #79afaf;
  right: 40px;
}

.remove,.complete{
 margin: 10px;

}

.remove,.complete{
  padding-top: 6px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

 <div class = "containtodolist">
  <header>
  <input id = "addtask_TD" type = "text" placeholder = "Add task">
   <button id = "add">
    
    
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 16;" xml:space="preserve"><g><path class="fill" d="M16,8c0,0.5-0.5,1-1,1H9v6c0,0.5-0.5,1-1,1s-1-0.5-1-1V9H1C0.5,9,0,8.5,0,8s0.5-1,1-1h6V1c0-0.5,0.5-1,1-1s1,0.5,1,1v6h6C15.5,7,16,7.5,16,8z"/></g></svg>
   </button>
  </header>
  
  
  <div class = "container_TD" id = "todo">
 <!-- <ul class = "todo" id = "completed">
   <li> WHouha 
    <div class = "buttons">
     <button class = "remove"> <img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/delete.png" width = "22px"></button>
     <button class = "complete"><img src = "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/11/28/857777_circle_512x512.png" width = "22px"> </button>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>-->
  </div>
  
<ul class = "todo" id = "completed">
   </ul>
```

Comment: Wow, I did not expect the solution to be so simple (I added [0], that's why). However, I tried the same tactic for replacing the check image, however, the issue remains.